# Probability for two distinguishable particles in same state

Tags: thermodynamics

In Maxwell Boltzmann system, two distinguishable particles which can exist in any of two energy states $0$ or $E$. I am trying to find out the probability of finding both particles in ground state.  I know that probability function in given state $j$ is 
$$
P_j=\frac{e^{-βEj}}{Z_1}
$$
where $Z_1$ is single particle partition function. And $P_j$ is the probability of a single particle in that state. If I write $Z_\mathrm{both\;particles}=Z_1^n$. So in this case $$Z_1=1+e^{-βE}$$ while
$$
Z_\mathrm{both\;particles}=\left(1+e^{-βE}\right)^2\;.
$$
And if I write the probability of single particle in ground state (0 state) I have 
$$
P_0=\frac{e^{-β\times0}}{1+e^{-βE}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-βE}}\;.
$$
 But this is the probability for single particle how can I write this probability for both particles in this (ground) state?

Comment: By asserting that $Z_{\mathrm{both particles}}=Z_1^2$, I believe you're essentially asserting that there are no interactions, which means their probabilities of existing in a given state are independent of each other. Just multiply the two probabilities together.

Comment: What if the particles will be interacting??

Comment: Then your partition function will probably look different, in general like $Z=\sum_i e^{-\beta E_{i}}$, where $E_{i}$ is the total energy of the system in microstate $i$. The non-interacting assumption is what lets you assume that the partition function is separable, if I remember correctly.